# Remove specific tags from html while avoiding iframes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to remove some specific tag from HTML example.
To avoid using iframe, I am getting an HTML page in my PHP file using `curl` and using getJSON. I am getting the result in my.js, 
but I am not taking the whole HTML and pasting it in my own div.
I guess the reason for this is that I can not have more than one HTML, HEAD, and BODY tag in one HTML structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>some style</style>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        The content of the document......
    </body>
</html>
```

Now in the above structure I do not need HTML, BODY, and HEAD tags, but I do need a STYLE tag for CSS so I just want to remove HTML, BODY, and HEAD tags.
After removing I need to append this to my div (all this trouble is because I do not want to use iframes).
How do I remove it? I thought of `strip_tags()` and `preg_replace` or some regex function, but couldn't understand the best way to do it.
Please help me find the best way to do this.
It could be in PHP, JavaScript, or JQuery. 
but i would appriciate if answer are in javascript and jquery since i would like to do this manupulation in my JS but if needed PHP will also  work

Comment: do you distinguish server-side and client-side?  plese rephrase your question with this in mind

Comment: Do you trust the content of the page you are sucking into your site?  If not you are quite vulnerable to client and server side attacks using this technique.

Comment: Thanks for editing @brad Mace

Comment: @LuisSiquot: yes i do, in client side i need only the content which i will be appending to my div, not the whole HTML structure and that is my how do remove the tags in such a way that i get the structure which can be appended to my div ??

Comment: yes i do trust the content which  i am sucking from that site @AllInOne

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM Parser, regex is not to be used for parsing HTML.

The following example uses the `DOMDocument` parser to extract the elements you want. `$html` is the HTLM document retrieved with cURL.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$styleNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName("style")->item(0);
$style = $dom->saveHTML($styleNode);
$body = "";
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $body .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}

echo $style;
echo $body;
```

Assuming this script is being called with getJson create a json object with `$style` and `$body` and pass it back to the javascript to be inserted into the page.

As I understand your question, this should be your application flow:

> Client loads page -> .getJSON invokes a php script -> said php script loads content from somewhere else with cURL -> this code runs -> json object is passed back to .getJSON -> the success callback from .getJSON adds the new HTML to the page

Comment: Status is ok but i am not getting any response for this function

Answer (score 0):

why not use the $strip_tag var in php to strip with exceptions?

Comment: What is the `$strip_tag` var? I have never heard of this.

Comment: I believe he means the php function strip_tags() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: but how do you use exception there